# Do different Azure Functions run on the same Node.js process?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Let's say I have 10 Azure Functions inside one Function App. Each one runs on timer on the 0th second of each minute.

Suppose these functions have blocking non-asynchronous code.

If one function blocks the Node.js process, will the other nine functions continue to run (because they are on different processes) or will they be blocked (because all functions inside a function app run on the same process)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Different functions within a function app do run on the same Node process. Whether the other nine functions are blocked is dependent on the nature of blocking synchronous code and how Node handles it.

You can see what process are running on the Function app by accessing kudu endpoint.
https://FunctionAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/ProcessExplorer/